# Calling a stored procedure from another stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have two fairly large and complex stored procedures.  I want to call a second stored procedure from the first stored procedure.  For example:

```
-- stored_procedure_one
select tb1.col1, tb1.col2, sp1.col3, sp1.col4
from table1 tb1
inner join stored_procedure_two sp1 on sp1.col1 = tbl1.col1
```

Is something similar possible with SQL as the above script gives me an invalid object error message.

Using a temp table is not good in this example, because if I did that, it would take an hour just to fill the temp table with all the data from the second stored procedure.  I only want the stored procedure to return the needed data.

Comment: Do you really need all 50 million rows or some summed output records based on certain ids?  You should probably rethink your query and create one that is more suited for this particular case than try to mingle two seperate queries into some frankenstein query because you didn't want to refactor.  The time spent could be worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not going to work. You cannot join on a stored procedure. However, you could consider changing stored_procedure_two into a [table-valued user defined function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=SQL.105).aspx). You could then 'join' via a Cross Apply. I have done this on numerous occasions and it works quite well.

If the second stored procedure is too large and complex, it may not be possible to convert to a UDF. In this case, I think your only alternative is to save the results of the second stored proc to a table and join on that. But that could be somewhat inefficient and messy.

Comment: This sounds more reasonable than using pre-filling a temp table with 50 million rows.  I will check it out now.  Thanks.

Comment: Would a view be possible?  i.e have the complexity of stored procedure two in a view, and then inner join with the view in stored procedure one?

Comment: we need to see the procedure to tell you that

Comment: @OGHaza, it's too much to post here.  But basically, sp2 has multiple defined tables, selects, inserts, unions, and even concatenation via `for xml path`.  I don't know much about views, so I'mn not sure if a view can have all that?  If not, what if I called the view from sp1 passing it a value from sp1, then the view gets populated from sp2 based only on the value from sp1?

Answer (score 0):

You may add the results of the second procedure in a local variable table

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
  Col1 int,
  Col2 ...
)

INSERT INTO @Table
EXEC stored_procedure_two

select tb1.col1, tb1.col2, sp1.col3, sp1.col4
from table1 tb1
inner join @Table tbl2 on sp1.col1 = tbl1.col1
```

Comment: As I tried explaining in the last paragraph of my question, I don't think this is very practical for my specific situation.

Comment: Yeap, noticed that now. Well, if you want the sp, this is one way to do it. The other way is as suggested to have a table valued function. But even this would lead to have the same code twice.

Comment: @OGHaza, I can't do that because if I run stored procedure two in it's entirety, it takes about an hour, which is why I only wanted to run part of it based on stored procedure one and an inner join to only get the required data from stored procedure two.

Comment: @oshirowanen, sorry yeah i realised what you meant and deleted the comment before you replied. still, I suspect the answer to this is to eliminate that first stored procedure from the mix entirely/give it extra parameters such that you can filter the results from the outset